# Inconsistent Slide Animation in a JavaScript Switch

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, slider, carousel

I am trying to implement a left/right sliding animation inside of a JavaScript switch statement and the animation (sliding left and right without a bounce effect and no whitespace in between images) is not consistently activating. Also, the slide animation still activates when the previous button is clicked on the first slide and when the next button is clicked on the last slide. This should not be happening. Does anyone have any thoughts? Please see the code example.

```js
$(function() {
 // USER EDITABLE CONTROLS
 var content = 'img'; // accepts any DOM element - div, img, table, etc...
 var showControls = true; // true/false shows/hides the slider's navigational controls
 var transition = 'slide'; // supports default, fade, slide
 var transitionDuration = .5; // adjust the time of the transition measured in seconds
 
 // VARIABLE DECLARATIONS
 var contentType = $(content);
 var $el = $('#showcase');
 var $leftArrow = '#left_arrow';
 var $rightArrow = '#right_arrow';
 var $load = $el.find(contentType)[0];
 var slideCount = $el.children().length;
 var slideNum = 1;
 
 // PRELOADS SLIDE WITH CORRECT SETTINGS
 $load.className = 'active';
 
 // ADD SLIDER CONTROLS TO PAGE
 if (showControls === true) {
  $('<div id="controls"><a href="#" id="' + $leftArrow.replace('#', '') + '">&laquo; Previous</a> <a href="#" id="' + $rightArrow.replace('#', '') + '">Next &raquo;</a></div>').insertAfter('#showcase');
  $('#controls').find('#left_arrow').addClass('disabled');
 }
 
 // LOGIC FOR SLIDE TRANSITIONS
 function transitions() {
  switch (transition) {
   // FADE TRANSITION
   case 'fade':
    $('.slide').stop().animate({opacity : 0}, transitionDuration*300, function(){
     $('.active').stop().animate({opacity : 1}, transitionDuration*1000);
    });
    break;

   // SLIDE TRANSITION
   case 'slide':
    if (slideNum > 1) {
     $('.slide').stop().animate({left : -160}, transitionDuration*800, function(){
      $('.active').stop().animate({left : 0}, transitionDuration*1000);
     });
    }
    
    if (slideNum < slideCount) {
     $('.slide').stop().animate({left : 160}, transitionDuration*800, function(){
      $('.active').stop().animate({left : 0}, transitionDuration*1000);
     });
    }
    break;

   // DEFAULT TRANSITION
   case 'default':
    break;
  }
 }
 
 // CHECKS FOR FIRST AND LAST INDEX IN THE SLIDER
 function checkSlide() {
  if (slideNum == 1) {
   $($leftArrow).addClass('disabled');
  } else {
   $($leftArrow).removeClass('disabled');
  }
  
  if (slideNum == slideCount) {
   $($rightArrow).addClass('disabled');
  } else {
   $($rightArrow).removeClass('disabled');
  }
 }

 // NAVIGATIONAL LOGIC FOR PREVIOUS/NEXT BUTTONS
 $(document).on('click', $leftArrow, function() {
  if (slideNum > 1) {
   var counter = $('.active').index();
      counter--;
   $('.active').addClass('slide');
   $('.active').removeClass('active');
   transitions();
   $el.find(contentType).eq(counter).addClass('active');
   slideNum--;
   checkSlide();
  }
 })
 
 $(document).on('click', $rightArrow, function() {
  if (slideNum < slideCount) {
   var counter = $('.active').index();
      counter++;
   $('.active').addClass('slide');
   $('.active').removeClass('active');
   transitions();
   $el.find(contentType).eq(counter).addClass('active');
   slideNum++;
   checkSlide();
  }
 })
});
```

```css
#showcase {
 width: 160px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

img {
 width: 160px;
}

a {
 color: blue;
}

.disabled {
 color: red !important;
}

.slide {
 display: none;
 opacity: 0;
 position: relative;
 left: 0px;
 right: 0px;
}

.active {
 display: block;
 opacity: 1;
 position: relative;
 left: 0px;
 right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="showcase">
 <img class="slide" src="https://picsum.photos/458/354" />
 <img class="slide" src="https://picsum.photos/458/354/?image=306" />
 <img class="slide" src="https://picsum.photos/458/354/?image=626" />
</div>
```

Comment: The animation still continues when button is clicked at the extreme left and right images because you bind a `click` function on the `transitions()` function which does not have conditional statements like that one you have on `$(document).on('click', $rightArrow, function() {`

Comment: @95faf8e76605e973 - I have updated the code to include the conditionals. Your response does not assist with the root of the problem though which is the inconsistent animation.

Comment: lol that is not my point - my point is you have two handlers for each button and both will trigger - 1 handler will not override another. try to simulate your code

Comment: @95faf8e76605e973 - I appreciate your feedback but I don't think I'm understanding you correctly. Would you mind posting a code sample/example of what you are talking about? I've added the conditionals to my switch which will determine if the left or right navigational link is clicked but I'm still experiencing the same issues.

Comment: ah ok. see you have `$(document).on('click', $rightArrow, function() {` and `$("#right_arrow").click(function () {` know what i mean? you have binded two click handlers to the rightarrow button. that is why _the slide animation still activates when the previous button is clicked on the first slide and when the next button is clicked on the last slide_

Comment: did you get what i mean bro? look like you got it now - good job

Comment: @95faf8e76605e973 yeah man, thank you! My slide transitions are still messed up though. For example, clicking on the Next link should cause an image to slide in from the right and clicking on the Previous link should cause an image to slide in from the left. Right now this is not happening. Do you have any thoughts on this?

Comment: yeah you need to change your conditions a little - let me right you an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comments you need to fix your conditional statements. Awhile ago you had set two `click` handlers - one of which is binded (and is triggered regardless of any condition) when the other handler is triggered, this caused *the slide animation still activates when the previous button is clicked on the first slide and when the next button is clicked on the last slide* issue.
As for the animations, see my code below. I hacked your conditions a litte. When previous is clicked, the slide is to move from left to right. When next is clicked the slide is to move from right to left. I used a flag to determine the movement it will make - see the new paramter for transition function

```js
$(function() {
  // USER EDITABLE CONTROLS
  var content = 'img'; // accepts any DOM element - div, img, table, etc...
  var showControls = true; // true/false shows/hides the slider's navigational controls
  var transition = 'slide'; // supports default, fade, slide
  var transitionDuration = .5; // adjust the time of the transition measured in seconds

  // VARIABLE DECLARATIONS
  var contentType = $(content);
  var $el = $('#showcase');
  var $leftArrow = '#left_arrow';
  var $rightArrow = '#right_arrow';
  var $load = $el.find(contentType)[0];
  var slideCount = $el.children().length;
  var slideNum = 1;

  // PRELOADS SLIDE WITH CORRECT SETTINGS
  $load.className = 'active';

  // ADD SLIDER CONTROLS TO PAGE
  if (showControls === true) {
    $('<div id="controls"><a href="#" id="' + $leftArrow.replace('#', '') + '">&laquo; Previous</a> <a href="#" id="' + $rightArrow.replace('#', '') + '">Next &raquo;</a></div>').insertAfter('#showcase');
    $('#controls').find('#left_arrow').addClass('disabled');
  }

  // LOGIC FOR SLIDE TRANSITIONS
  function transitions(impl = null) {
    switch (transition) {
      // FADE TRANSITION
      case 'fade':
        $('.slide').stop().animate({
          opacity: 0
        }, transitionDuration * 300, function() {
          $('.active').stop().animate({
            opacity: 1
          }, transitionDuration * 1000);
        });
        break;

        // SLIDE TRANSITION
      case 'slide':
        if (impl == "next") {
          $('.slide').css("left", '160px');
          $('.slide').stop().animate({
            left: 160
          }, transitionDuration * 800, function() {
            $('.active').stop().animate({
              left: 0
            }, transitionDuration * 1000);
          });
        } else if (impl == "prev") {
          $('.slide').css("left", '-160px');
          $('.slide').stop().animate({
            left: -160
          }, transitionDuration * 800, function() {
            $('.active').stop().animate({
              left: 0
            }, transitionDuration * 1000);
          });
        }
        break;

        // DEFAULT TRANSITION
      case 'default':
        break;
    }
  }

  // CHECKS FOR FIRST AND LAST INDEX IN THE SLIDER
  function checkSlide() {
    if (slideNum == 1) {
      $($leftArrow).addClass('disabled');
    } else {
      $($leftArrow).removeClass('disabled');
    }

    if (slideNum == slideCount) {
      $($rightArrow).addClass('disabled');
    } else {
      $($rightArrow).removeClass('disabled');
    }
  }

  // NAVIGATIONAL LOGIC FOR PREVIOUS/NEXT BUTTONS
  $(document).on('click', $leftArrow, function() {
    if (slideNum > 1) {
      var counter = $('.active').index();
      counter--;
      $('.active').addClass('slide');
      $('.active').removeClass('active');
      transitions('prev');
      $el.find(contentType).eq(counter).addClass('active');
      slideNum--;
      checkSlide();
    }
  })

  $(document).on('click', $rightArrow, function() {
    if (slideNum < slideCount) {
      var counter = $('.active').index();
      counter++;
      $('.active').addClass('slide');
      $('.active').removeClass('active');
      transitions('next');
      $el.find(contentType).eq(counter).addClass('active');
      slideNum++;
      checkSlide();
    }
  })
});
```

```css
#showcase {
  width: 160px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  width: 160px;
}

a {
  color: blue;
}

.disabled {
  color: red !important;
}

.slide {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}

.active {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="showcase">
  <img class="slide" src="https://picsum.photos/458/354" />
  <img class="slide" style="left: 160px;" src="https://picsum.photos/458/354/?image=306" />
  <img class="slide" style="left: 160px;" src="https://picsum.photos/458/354/?image=626" />
</div>
```

Comment: thank you! I see what you did. By setting the left positions of .slide when the click action is "Previous/Next" you allow for a smooth and consistent transition to the next piece of content. Thank you for your explanation and example.